# What does .$ mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer

I was in the console trying something when i saw that the .$ can be used along with the document object to access the elements. But i don't know what it actually does.

example :-
[image]

Comment: Probably something a library like jQuery added to the element.

Comment: but i can access the elements inside the first #shadow-root but cannot inside the next one

Comment: Must mean that a script adds this property. It is not part of the DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) interface.

Comment: @trincot do you know how can we access that shot of elements using the console

Comment: from looking at the warning at the top of your console (which I get too), and sniffing around that same Chrome cookies page, I *think* it's something to do with PolymerJS. But it's not a library I'm familiar with, and I haven't found anything in their docs which indicates what this property is or what it does - so I'm far from sure. It's definitely either a third-party library or some custom code though which is adding this property - it won't work on most elements on most webpages.

Comment: this.$ is the equivalent to `this.shadowRoot.getElementById()`, and you can use this.$$ as an alias for `this.shadowRoot.querySelector()`. It's Polymer specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After some detective work, my guess it is a [special Polymer component property](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding):**

> #### Automatic node finding
>
> Polymer automatically builds a map of statically created instance nodes in its local DOM, to provide
> convenient access to frequently used nodes without the need to query
> for them manually. Any node specified in the element's template with
> an id is stored on the this.$ hash by id.

I am not familiar with Polymer, and it is very difficult to find (recent) documentation on this property.

However I believe my guess is correct based on the description above and the screen shot below. As you can see, if you add another `.` after the `$` you get a list of suggested properties. These are all ids in the DOM:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped me alot understanding that. so i will give you the bounty wait 1-2 hrs till i am able to give it.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that may be any global object under jquery. Exactly, I don't have any experience with .$ but surf the official docs of Jquery, it may help or another possibility is that it is something coming from backend of from database. There may be a lot of reason. Hope, it helps..

Answer (score -1):

This should be a property added to the element but is not anything special.

An example would be like

```js
let a = {};
a.$ = {
  b: 1,
  c: 2
};
console.log(a.$);
```

This will also give you the object properties of `$` in `a`.

A bonus fun fact is, in Javascript, emoji is also valid as property name, and therefore

```js
let a = {};
a.$ = {
  "": 1,
  "": 2
};
console.log(a.$[""]);
```

also works